# jQGrid primary key issue when delete

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have primary key of my row as hidden field in my jQGrid. It is called "UserId"

```
colNames: ['UserId', "Details" ...],
colModel: [{ name: 'UserId', index: 'UserId', editable: false, hidden: true },
          { name: 'Details', index: 'Details', editable: true, editactioniconscolumn: true },
           ...]
```

I get worked create and update cases but i have an issue with delete

Because when delete i am getting an `Id` of the grid row back on controller and not `UserId`,
I can keep all `UserId's` in grid id, that is what i am currently done to make delete work, but i am wondering is there any way to get my hidden `UserId` getting posted instead of grid row Id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement your requirements in many ways:

1. If the value from the `UserId` column is unique on the page and can be used to identify the row you can add `key:true` property to the `UserId` column definition in the `colModel`.
2. You can use [beforeSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) or [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) event to modify the `postdata` parameter and add additional information which will be send to the server. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475629/jqgrid-and-zend-framework-trouble/3480239#3480239) for an example.
3. Use [delData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) property exactly like `editData` which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184399/add-additional-param-to-post-data-using-jqgrid-when-adding-new-row-with-modal-for/6184668#6184668).
4. Use [serializeDelData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) event. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122392/jqgrid-delete-a-row/6122658#6122658) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917102/jqgrid-add-row-and-send-data-to-webservice-for-insert/3918615#3918615).