# How do I send data from my JQGrid to my query to delete a row?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, coldfusion

I am unable to delete a row from my JQGrid because I can't figure out how to send the data I need to the file that holds the MySQL. I am using ColdFusion.

In my JQGrid file, my editurl parameter is set as such:

```
editurl: url+"process_delete.cfc?method=process_delete&region="+region,
```

In my process_delete.cfc file, that holds my MySQL queries, I have this:

```
DELETE FROM awesome_table
WHERE region = '#region#' AND Field1 = '??????' AND Field2 = '???????'
```

I know that the MySQL is being reached - no problems there. Also, the region is populated just fine from the URL. No problems there. The problem is that I can't figure out how to access the data from the row I'm trying to delete in order to populate Field1 and Field2, effectively completing the query. Can anyone help? Thanks.

For Delete I have the following code:

```
jQuery.jgrid.del = {
            caption: "Delete Item",
            msg: "Delete record?",
            bSubmit: "Delete",
            bCancel: "Cancel",
            beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid) { 
                var rowid = $("#mygrid").getGridParam('selrow');
                $("#mygrid").jqGrid('saveRow',rowid,false,'clientArray');
                var rowvalues = $("#mygrid").getRowData(rowid);
                return [true, ""]
            }
```

When I display the `rowid` in an alert message box, I get "null" back, so maybe that's where my problem stems from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `delData` with the properties `field1` and `field2` defined as functions or to use `onclickSubmit` or `beforeSubmit` in which you can dynamically modify the `URL` used in the DELETE operation or to use `serializeDelData` callback. The best way could depend on other options which you use (for example depends on `mtype` used for Delete operation). In [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6275312/315935) I included the references to other answers which shows all the ways in details.

For example you can use

```
onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
    // we suppose that use don't use multiselect: true option
    // in the case rowid parameter if the string with the id of the
    // deleted row

    // we can get the data about the deleted row with respect of
    // getCell, getLocalRow or getRowData methods
    var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData", rowid);

    // now we can modify the URL used in the Delete operation
    options.url += "?" + $.param({
        field1: rowData.field1,
        field2: rowData.field2
    });

    return {}; // you can return additional data which will be sent to the server
}
```

Comment: The mtype I am using is 'GET'.

Comment: @Louise: I suppose that you don't use `mtype: "GET"` for the Delete operation. :-) The default value of `mtype` for the Delete operation is `"POST"`. In some cases (RESTful services) you can prefer `mtype: "DELETE"`.

Comment: @Louise: The code which you posted makes the problem not clearly. Inside of `beforeSubmit` of Delete implementation you call `saveRow` with `'clientArray'` parameter which save locally the data editing with respect of inline editing. I don't understand why you need this. Moreover the data of `rowvalues` will be discarded. By the way you can better to use `$(this)` instead of `$("#mygrid")` to have less dependencies in the code. In any way the code which you posted don't clear your main question about sending of additional data during deleting of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot really help much without seeing your code that comes back from your CFC to populate the grid.  However, one approach is to access the id of the row and put it in some HTML element like an anchor tag, for example:

If you are creating a loop to prepare your data

```
//Some loop
<cfset dataRows[i]['id'] = #yourqueryId# />
<cfset dataRows[i]['cell'] = "<a href="##" class="delete" id="#yourqueryId#">Delete</a>" />
```

Then you pass your JSON object to the CFM file

```
 <cfset JSONReturn = {total=#totalPages#,page=#page#,records=#recordcount#,rows=dataRows} />
```

Then in the page that displays the grid add an event that handles the click of the anchor tag

```
$('a.delete').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //do something with the id
})
```

Hope that helps!