# Jqgrid custom form and custom function

Tags: jqgrid

I have the following problem. I m using a custom form for Jqgrid, the problem is that I can t figure it out how can I use different functions for submit button in add/edit/delete. Can you help me? I can use delfunc with succes. How can I add delfunc to the button submit from del form, and the function addfunc to submit button from the form of add.

```
$('#jqGrid').navGrid("#jqGridPager", {
    edit: true, 
    add: true,
    del: true, 
    refresh: true, 
    view: false,
    addfunc : function(){
       var angajat = new Object();
       angajat.id = null;
       angajat.firstName = "andrei"  //jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getRowData');
       angajat.lastName = " chivu " //jQuery("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getRowData');
    console.log(angajat);

     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "rest/user/add",
         data: JSON.stringify(angajat),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json",
         success: function (data) {
         $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(data));
         }

     });

    },
    delfunc : function (id){

        $.ajax({
            type:"DELETE",
            url:"rest/user/delete",
            data:JSON.stringify(id),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",

        }).done(function( msg ) {
            alert("Content Deleted: " + id);},
            jQuery("#jqGrid").trigger("reloadGrid"));
         },

          editCaption: "Update Employee",
            template: template,
            //onClick: alert("alaaaaa"),
             errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                 return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
             }
         },
         // options for the Add Dialog
         {
            addCaption: "Add new Employee",
            template: template,
            sData: alert("alaaaaa"),
            errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                 return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
             }
         },
         // options for the Delete Dialog

{    
             caption: "Delete the Employee",
             msg: "Are you sure ? ",
             beforeSubmit: alert("alaaaaa"),

             errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                 return 'Error: ' + data.responseText
             },

         });
```

});

Comment: Sorry, but the shorter is your question the more expect your for the person who answer your question. Other people have a lot of other things to do. Instead of writing that you have "a custom form" you could post the link to demo, post the code or the code fragment and so on. It's absolutely unclear which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in which version you use. How you start add/edit/delete? Do you use `navGrid` or call the methods directly?

Comment: done, it s ok now?:)

Comment: I see now that you use `addfunc` and `delfunc`. What about other my questions. Which version and fork of jqGrid you use? You use `"#response"`. What is the element? I still can't follow you. You had some problem in the standard form editing and have chosen complex way with `addfunc` and `delfunc`. Thus you try to solve some problem. Which one? I see no advantage in your custom code. For example `delfunc` just makes Ajax request and you can use standard jqGrid option to do the same. Moreover I don't understand your main question. What problem you have and which kind of help you expect?

Comment: I used delfunc and addfunc because I didn t know how to make the call for java backend app. I don t know what "#response" is, I found this example http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/ and I tried to use it. I just want to be able to make delete and add on my server, and delfunc and adfunc is the only way that  let me do it. Also for jqgrid I have only this link "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js". Can you tell me how I can attached a trigger to Submit button for add edit and delete?

Comment: OK I can post my answer where I explain how to call RESTful services from `navGrid`, but I can explain it on the example of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) and not for Guriddo jqGrid JS. I develop free jqGrid, don't know the last changes of Guriddo and I implemented some features in free jqGrid which simplify the usage of REST. Thus if you confirm that free jqGrid whould be helpful for you then I'll post my answer.

Comment: of course free jqGrid is helpful for me. I confirm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One don't need to use `delfunc`, `addfunc`, `editfunc` or `viewfunc` in the most cases. The function are replacements for `delGridRow`, `editGridRow` and `viewGridRow`, but to replace the methods which code is not so small one have to understand the code in details.

I try to explain your problem how I understand it. I'll start with the usage of `delfunc`. What you try to do is calling of URL `rest/user/delete` using HTTP DELETE. Thus I suppose that you have RESTful services on the backend. To use HTTP DELETE you need to append the id of deleted item to the URL, use DELETE operation and be sure that no other information (like `oper` parameter) are placed in HTTP body. Thus you can use existing options of `delGridRow`.

It's important to understand that `navGrid` just add some buttons in the navigator bar and it calls the methods `delGridRow`, `editGridRow` and `viewGridRow` if the user clicks on the corresponding buttons. The options of `navGrid` looks like

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid('navGrid','#gridpager', {parameters},
    prmEdit, prmAdd, prmDel, prmSearch, prmView);
```

(see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition)). The `parameters` parts are real options of `navGrid` and it informs `navGrid` for example which buttons should be included on the navigator bar. The other options are the options of  `delGridRow`, `editGridRow`, `searchGrid` and `viewGridRow` methods which shoule be used if the user clicks on the corresponding button of navigator bar. To configure the behavior of Delete button we need to specify `prmDel` parameter. The value of the parameter should be object with the properties and 
callbacks of `delGridRow` method. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow).

In the same way if one uses `formatter: "actions"` or `inlineNav` then another buttons will be added and one have to use the corresponding options to specify, which options of `delGridRow` should be used. 
I find that the options of `navGrid` is difficult to understand. Because of that I introduced in free jqGrid alternative way of specify default options used in jqGrid by `delGridRow` inside of `formDeleting` *of jqGrid options*. Thus the most free jqGrid looks like [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm). It uses `formEditing`, `formViewing`, `searching` options of jqGrid and the call of `navGrid` is either without any parameters or with the small set of options. Now back to your main problems. See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for more information.

If the main logic is clear then it will be clear how one configure jqGrid to do on Delete exactly what you need. To do this you should specify `mtype: "DELETE"` option and `ajaxDelOptions: {...}` to specify other options of Ajax call. To append the id to the URL you can use `onclickSubmit` or `beforeSubmit` callbacks (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330854/315935)), but in free jqGrid and can use `url` defined as function (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34721322/315935)) and have more readable code. Thus I suggest you to use `formDeleting` option with the value

```
{
    mtype: "DELETE",
    url: function (rowid) {
        return "/rest/user/delete/" + rowid;
    },
    ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    serializeDelData: function () {
        return "";
    },
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
}
```

The grid will be reloaded automatically on successful deleting because `reloadAfterSubmit: true` is default option of `delGridRow` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2)). The last option `reloadGridOptions` is helpful in case of usage `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. It will force reloading of grid from the server.

In the same way to configure Add and Edit buttons you can use `formEditing` option of jqGrid with the value

```
{
    url: function (id, editOrAdd) {
        return "/rest/user/" + (editOrAdd === "add" ? "add" : "edit");
    },
    mtype: function (editOrAdd) {
        return editOrAdd === "add" ? "POST" : "PUT";
    }, 
    serializeEditData: function (postData) {     
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    serializeEditData: function (postData) {
        var dataToSend = $.extend({}, postData); // make copy of data
        // don't send any id in case of creating new row or to send `0`:
        if (dataToSend.id === "_empty") {
            delete dataToSend.id; // or dataToSend.id = 0; 
        }
        return JSON.stringify(dataToSend);
    },
    ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
}
```